# Responsive menu problems

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm currently working on http://jonathan.ohrstrom.nu and I'm trying to get the links to the right to function with a responsive design. Making it if the windows is less than 1000px wide, then the links disappear and a menu-button appears instead; creating a drop-down menu.

```js
 /* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("topnav");
        if (x.className === "menuList") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "menuList";
        }
    }
```

```css
    .menu_wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     height: 70px;
     background-color: rgba(45, 45, 45, .9);
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 99;
     box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(229, 160, 0, .9);
    }
    .menu_content {
     width: 1000px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     line-height: 70px;
     color: #a0a0a0;
     font-weight: 400;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .menu_logo {
     float: left;
     font-size: 18px;
    }
    a.logotyp, a.logotyp:visited {
     color: white;
     transition: .1s;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    a.logotyp:hover {
     color: #a0a0a0;
    }
    
    ul.menuList {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    ul.menuList li.icon {
     display: none;
    }
    
    ul.menuList li {
     float: right;
     display: inline;
     margin: 0 10px;
    }
    
    ul.menuList li a {
     color: #a0a0a0;
     transition: .1s;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul.menuList li a:hover {
     color: #e5a000;
    }
    
    /* RESPONSIVE MENU */
    @media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
      ul.menuList li {display: none;}
      ul.menuList li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
      ul.menuList.responsive {position: relative;}
      ul.menuList.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      ul.menuList.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
      }
      ul.menuList.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <!-- MENU -->
     <div class="menu_wrapper">
     
      <div class="menu_content">
       
       <div class="menu_logo">
        <a href="#top" class="logotyp">&lt;/ECORND></a>
       </div>
       
       <div class="menu_links">
        <ul class="menuList" id="topnav">
         <li><a href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
         <li><a href="#projekt">projekt</a></li>
         <li><a href="#tjänster">Tjänster</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about">info</a></li>
         <li><a href="#top">hem</a></li>
         <li class="icon">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       
      </div>
     
     </div>
```

But if you look at the site, the dropdown doesn't really work any good and the drop-down button is not following the window width.. What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I got most of the code from w3school's responsive tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this style:

```
ul.menuList li.icon {
    float: right;
}
```

add below  to style.css line no:77

```
ul.menuList li.icon {
   position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The dropdown button follows the width of the browser now! The only issue left is the drop-down menu, it doesn't follow the width, it's too far up and the text is floating to the right so some words cannot be seen (I can probably fix the last one myself)

Comment: EDIT: I overestimated my abilities, trying to get the dropdown-text aligned to the right just got the whole bunch of text going to the right.. Also the dropdown button moves to the right when clicked for some reason

Comment: hmmm, all the best..!